# AsyncTask doesn't stop even after cancelling it

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask inside a fragment, which is being executed every second using a Timer. The AsyncTask loads data into a ListView, and when the user clicks on a ListView item, it switches to another fragment.

The timer doesn't stop, so it keeps executing itself and finally, gives me an error when it tries to load the data into the ListView.

I already tried looking for answers, and have implemented those in my code-

```
class HttpGetAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        Log.d("PORTS Cancelled","cancelled");

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... q) {

        String v = null, c = null;
        for(int countervar=0;countervar<1;countervar++){
            if(load.isCancelled())  
                break;
            //All my code here
        }

        return c;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if(isCancelled()||!isAdded()){
            return;
        }
        else{
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                ports, R.layout.playout, new String[] { "name",
            "code", "type" }, new int[] { R.id.portn, R.id.portc,
            R.id.portv });
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

}

@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        timer.cancel(); //timer is the name of the Timer
        doAsynchronousTask.cancel(); //doAsynchronousTask is the TimerTask
        if(load!=null)          //load is the AsyncTask
            if(!load.isCancelled())
               load.cancel(true);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    timer.cancel();
    doAsynchronousTask.cancel();
    if(load!=null)
        if(!load.isCancelled())
            load.cancel(true);
}
```

The timer (Called in `onCreateView`)-

```
handler = new Handler();
            doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {       
                            try {
                                load = new HttpGetAsyncTask();
                                load.execute();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 10000);
```

Please let me know where I'm going wrong and what I can do to fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Can we see the code used in the timer?

Comment: When the doAsynchronousTask task is scheduled the **load** variable is replaced with a new **HttpGetAsyncTask**. So more than one AsyncTask can run a the same time, and when you stop the task (calling load.cancel(true);), you are only cancelling the AsyncTask referenced by **load** variable.

Comment: @Joseph82 thanks! that worked. Please post that as an answer so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `doAsynchronousTask` task is scheduled the load variable is replaced with a new `HttpGetAsyncTask`. So more than one `AsyncTask` can run a the same time, and when you stop the task, calling:

`load.cancel(true);`,

you are only cancelling the `AsyncTask` referenced by load variable, but others tasks can continue to work in backgroud (without any handle for stopping them).

A solution can be, to stop the AsyncTask before start another one.

Comment: I didn't mention this earlier, so I'm sorry, but now that I've removed the `load = new HttpGetAsyncTask();` line, the AsyncTask doesn't get executed every second.Could you suggest something?

Comment: I think you can check the status of the task, and if it is still executing, then not execute a new one. You can check the status in this way: `load.getStatus()` and compare it with `AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING`. So `if(load==null || load.getStatus()!= AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
            load = new HttpGetAsyncTask();`

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a boolean flag in the loop as the condition controlling the loop?

Then you can set it to false to stop the task in onPause()